# PHP rowcount not returning correct result

Tags: php

I am trying to get the row count which should equal 2 but it returns 0 everytime.

```
$username = "matthew";
$query_url = array(':user' => $username);
$chek_url = $db->prepare("SELECT Id FROM Customer WHERE Referral = :user");
$chek_url->execute($query_url);
$signups = $chek_url->rowCount();
```

This definitely should return 2. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you see this part in the documentation? _"If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications."_

Comment: See example 2 here for the recommended way to check this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#refsect1-pdostatement.rowcount-examples

Comment: No, that's useful. Thank you

Comment: oh wow, that's a very ugly solution, thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, it's not great. In fact, I don't actually do that myself. I just fetch the rows and count them as I go if they need to be counted (in addition to whatever else I'm doing with them). A lot of people use the count to verify that the query actually returned something, but it isn't really necessary to count the results to check that.